# How to fix Dual boot missing UEFI mode bootloader in window 8.1

Tags: linux, dual-boot, gentoo, window

My notebook exist UEFI mode windows 8.1 before install linux. When I install the sabayon-linux missing windows bootloader. I tried the following solutions.But I can't. How to fix boot repair windows 8.1 UEFI-bootloader?

1. [How to repair windows 8 efibootloader](https://superuser.com/questions/460762/how-can-i-repair-the-windows-8-efi-bootloader)
2. [fix-uefi-boot](https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-uefi-boot/)
3. [enter link description here](http://www.itechs-systems.com/fix_corrupt_UEFI_partition.aspx)

Pls help me.